# How to solve NullPointerException in MediaPlayer SeekBar onStartTrackingTouch

Tags: java, android

Please i need help. If i click on play, the media seekbar will start and move but doesn't call for stop(); and return while the music comes to finish.
So i encounter this NullPointerException when click stop button and touch the seekbar. Please tell me what to do. The logcat error files is below.
I don't know how to make the seekbar stop

MediaPlayer Seekbar onStopTrackingTouch does not take effect while the music seekBar elapses to end. Instead, onStopTrackingTouch takes effect when i want to close the mediaplayer activity.

```
public void  play(View v) {
        if (player == null) {
            int i = 0;
            try{
                i=getIntent().getIntExtra("i",0);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String fileToPlay="music_"+i;




            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(fileToPlay,"raw",getPackageName()));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            soundSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            soundSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    if (fromUser){
                        player.seekTo(progress);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    soundSeekBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());



                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    player.getCurrentPosition();

                }
            });

            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                }

            });
        }
        player.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        soundThread = new Thread(this);
        soundThread.start();


    }
    public void pause(View v) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.pause();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
    public void stop(View v) {
        stopPlayer();
    }
    private void stopPlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tune Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int soundTotal = player.getDuration();
        soundSeekBar.setMax(soundTotal);
        while (player != null && currentPosition < soundTotal){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
                currentPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException soundException){
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception otherException){
                return;
            }
            soundSeekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }

    }
```

This is the logcat shewing the crash error.

```
2019-10-25 08:44:16.981 31938-31938/com.joseph.schoolproject E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2019-10-25 08:44:16.981 31938-31938/com.joseph.schoolproject E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-10-25 08:44:16.988 31938-31938/com.joseph.schoolproject E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()' on a null object reference
        at com.joseph.schoolproject.NewActivity$2.onStartTrackingTouch(NewActivity.java:223)
        at android.widget.SeekBar.onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:115)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.startDrag(AbsSeekBar.java:825)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:773)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12259)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:451)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3322)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12503)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5003)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6945)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6919)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6876)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7063)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
2019-10-25 08:44:16.988 31938-31938/com.joseph.schoolproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM




    --------- beginning of crash
2019-10-25 08:44:16.996 31938-31938/com.joseph.schoolproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.joseph.schoolproject, PID: 31938
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()' on a null object reference
        at com.joseph.schoolproject.NewActivity$2.onStartTrackingTouch(NewActivity.java:223)
        at android.widget.SeekBar.onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:115)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.startDrag(AbsSeekBar.java:825)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:773)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12259)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2658)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:451)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3322)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12503)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5003)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6945)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6919)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6876)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7063)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Comment: It's obvious...you are stopping your MediaPlayer which calls `player.release(); player == null` and after that on `onStartTrackingTouch ` you are trying to get the player's current position while it's already a null. If the question is how to fix the `NullPointerException` just check for null, but I think you should rethink your connection between the `SeekBar` and `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Okay @hardartcore please sir help me make the correction in the code i provided. thanks

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve. Can you explain a little bit more what are you trying to do?

Comment: The Explanation: I already have music files in raw folder. and in BaseAdapter i used Intent.putExtra to send the music files in position to the NewActivity.java which has the mediaplayer code above. Please sir i need your help!

Comment: I am asking more like what do you want to achieve with the `MeidiaPlayer` and the `Seekbar` ?

Comment: the media player has play, pause, & stop buttons,   I want the mediaplayer to startplaying with seekbar and to stop playing when the music seekbar elaspe to end. so that when the seekbar is touched to track play event, it will not throw NullPointerException. Thanks sir

Comment: Assuming i'm currently playing a music and want to stop player and touch/slide seekbar so as to track maybe the middle of music playing, the mediaplayer will immediately throw a NullPointerException. That is the only problem i have now.

Comment: Any help as regards this challenge i have would be appreciated!